# changing images using jquery hides text too

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to have a continuous loop of images on my webpage. The image is applied to the entire body and hence in jquery I am finding the body tag and editing its css background-image property.This functioning properly with the image but every time the image changes the text disappears too and reappears with the image. what am I doing wrong here please help

```
     $(window).load(function() {           
      var i =0; 
      var images = ['bookstore-indie.jpg', 'goat-farm-bookstore-1.jpg','bookstore.jpg'];
      var image = $('body');
       image.css('background-image', 'url(bookstore-indie.jpg)');
       setInterval(function(){   
       image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
       image.css('background-image', 'url(../img/' + images [i++] +')');
       image.fadeIn(1000);
       });
       if(i == images.length)
        i = 0;
      }, 5000);            
     });
```

Comment: You're setting your image variable to be the body. Therefor when you do image.fadeOut you're fading out the entire body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {           
  var i =0; 
  var images = ['bookstore-indie.jpg', 'goat-farm-bookstore-1.jpg','bookstore.jpg'];
  var image = $('body');
   image.css('background-image', 'url(bookstore-indie.jpg)').fadeIn(1000);
   setInterval(function(){   
       image.css('background-image', 'url(../img/' + images [i++] +')').fadeIn(1000);
   });
   if(i == images.length)
    i = 0;
  }, 5000);            
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`var image = $('body');` -> You are selecting the whole body here.

`image.fadeOut(1000, function () {` -> You are fading away the whole body here.

The body usually contains all the elements that will be visible for the user, fading away the body will make everything inside of it fade away also.